# Replace particular text message of a div using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, str-replace

I need to replace the text "Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record." inside `<div class="alert alert-error">`  with "You are not eligible to make this purchase."

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.
</div>
```

Its a dynamic code and I want to replace only that text not other text inside that class because the error text will be different according to behavior of the page.Is there any way I can find only this string "Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record." and replace it with customized text message using either jquery or java script.

Comment: You need to wrap up your error message in a class and you can use $('.alert .error-message').html()

Comment: If you cannot wrap the error message.. will that string to replace always be the same?

Comment: Its dynamic code i cant add class id or anything...i need to find the string first

Comment: @user2787474 what do you mean by dynamic code. Which part? I assume the error messages like 'Form+validation+failed..' are dynamic. So even dynamic, you can make a holder div class to display those dynamic messages.

Comment: @user2787474 your HTML is not neat. You should consider wrapping your "dynamic text" in span before sending it to this page. That way, you will have specific tags using which it will be easier to select in jQuery. Anyway, because you insist, you can use a dirty trick like I gave [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402738/replace-particuler-text-message-of-a-div-using-js-or-jquery/24406506#24406506). I reiterate that you should consider sending your string wrapped in a `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the `alert alert-error` classes using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName). You can then iterate over the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FHTMLCollection) returned by `getElementsByClassName`. Using replace to update the message, see below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var errors = document.getElementsByClassName("alert alert-error")
  for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    var div = errors.item(i)
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace("Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.", "User Authentication failed.")

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.
</div>
```

Comment: Its dynamic code i cant add class id or anything...i need to find the string first

Comment: im getting this error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

...validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.":"User Authentication failed.

Comment: its my code<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    errors = document.getElementsByClassName("alert alert-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
    {
        var div = errors.item(i);
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace("Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.", "You are not eligible to make this purchase");
    }
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

This one is a dirty thing to do but this does what you need.

```
$('div[class="alert alert-error"]:contains("Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.")')
    .html('<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>You are not eligible to make this purchase.');
```

***TIP:*** You can also simply use `$(.alert-error:contains("Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record."))` to select your `div` if you think that won't conflict with another DOM element

The code will first select a `<div class="alert alert-error">` and the check for the given content.  If a match is found,  it will replace the complete HTML inside the selected `div` with whatever is passed inside `.html()`.  Now,  you will have to pass the HTML for the button next to your text because there is no way(none that I know of) to select just the string you wanted within the `div`.  Had the string been in a wrapper,  it would have been much easier and nicer to select and replace it using `.replace()`.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2vCnk/)

Probably,  you should take  a look at the code that is giving this "dynamic content".  You can easily add a wrapper like `<span id="dynamic"></span>` around your "dynamic content" before passing it here.  If you could do that,  you could easily do something like

```
$('#dynamic:contains("Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.")').text('You are not eligible to make this purchase.');
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2vCnk/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap your text with `span` tag then you can easily accomplish the replacement. Try like:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
<span id="text_to_replace">Form+validation+failed.+You+cannot+submit+this+record.</span>
</div>
```

To replace the existing text with the new one you should use this:

```
$('#text_to_replace').html('You are not eligible to make this purchase.');
```

Comment: Its dynamic code i cant add class id or anything...i need to find the string first

Comment: Though dynamic but this text would be added somehow to your document, so what you need to do is place a span tag around the text in the code which adds it !

Comment: If i will add any span or div before that text it will get added to every error message.......so is there any way if that string is present that will be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Render your alert in span or other control.

Because put your text in div is bed practice of programming.

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsUp8/).

Check Fiddle you will got your answer.

```
$( ".close" ).click(function() {
  $(".message").html("Your Alert Message");
});
```